# How to get the closest dates in sqlite database to present date

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with a table that holds a column full of dates. I need to get the date closest to the present date out of everything in that column, but I don't know how to build a query for this.

For example I have the following dates in the column

```
3/15/2015
3/31/2015
4/15/2015
4/30/2015
5/15/2015
5/30/2015
```

If the current date is 4/20/2015 I need it to get all rows that have the date.

**EDIT**

For clarification I need the only the upcoming dates not the past dates.

```
4/30/2015
```

Also my dates are stored as string. Can anyone help?

**FINAL QUERY** courtesy of Loc Ha

```
Cursor trythis(String Date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] params = new String[]{String.valueOf(Date)};
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + colCompID + " as _id," + colCompClass + "," + colName + "," + colPayDue + "," + colDateDue + " FROM " + viewComps + " WHERE " + colDateDue + "=" + "( SELECT MIN (" + colDateDue + ") FROM " + PAYMENTS + " WHERE " + colDateDue + ">=?);", params);
    return cur;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want all results for only the current date no matter what? Or do you want all results for yesterday if there are no results for today?

Comment: @Numan1617 Sorry about that, I only need the closest upcoming date from the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t
WHERE t.date_col = 
  ( SELECT MIN (t2.date_col) FROM table t2
    WHERE t2.date_col >= ? );
```

? parameter will be passed with value is CURRENT date

IF date_col data type is Integer in SQLite, ? parameter will be passed with this value:  System.currentTimeMillis()

**Note:** You may have to remove time info such as hour, minute, second, millisecond from System.currentTimeMillis()

**Note 2:**
 If you use String as Data type in SQLite, you have to format System.currentTimeMillis() into Date format "yyyy/MM/dd". If you use other formats such as M/d/yyyy --> You will have date String comparing issues. See issue below for M/d/yyyy format:

```
"5/15/2015".compareTo("11/30/2015") ---> Return 4 > 0
--> means "5/15/2015" > "11/30/2015" --- Wrong
```

Comment: What do I do if my date_col data type is string though?

Comment: I'm getting the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcpetion: column '_id' does not exist. I'll post the code in an edit above so it's cleaner.

Comment: _id error is another issue. If you use CursorAdaptor, the table must have _id column.

Comment: Changed the code a bit. Still the same error, I'm missing something and for the life of me I can't figure it out. Also I applied it to a SimpleCursorAdapter in one of my gridviews

Comment: Make sure database table has column _id and your Java entity has field _id too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, a tree fell and knocked my internet out. Anyway got it to work, just needed an `as _id` in the query. Which personally I found weird since my VIEW already has an explicit `as _id` declaration but whatever. Thanks