# SQLite Query not working when dates are compared in where clause

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to Fetch records between two dates from SQLite table, But it doesn't work when Dates are compared in where clause, actually it works for other String column used as condition or when no where clause is specified, so is there any other way to use dates in where clause.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT min(activity_date), max(activity_date) FROM tbl_activity_details" , null);
if(cursor != null) {
    itemsList.clear();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        itemsList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        itemsList.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    cursor.close();
    try {
        fromDate = sdf.parse(itemsList.get(0));
        toDate = sdf.parse(itemsList.get(1));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "here "+sdf.format(fromDate)+"  "+sdf.format(toDate), 5000).show();
        //Toasts 2015-04-23 2015-05-01
        String fd = sdf.format(fromDate);
        String td = sdf.format(toDate);

        cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_activity_details WHERE activity_date BETWEEN '"+fd+"' AND '"+td+"'", null); 
        Toast.makeText(this, "here 1"+cursor1.getCount(), 5000).show();
        //Toasts here 1 10
        if(cursor1 != null) {
            while(cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "here 2"+cursor1.getString(0), 5000).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Record Found", 5000).show();
        }
        cursor1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: whats the format of the date inside your sqlite?

Comment: In above code cursor1.getCount() returns 10 means cursor contains 10 rows, But I'm unable to read records from that cursor, why does it happen ?

Comment: my date format is yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a similar question and the answer might help you out, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732261/how-to-get-the-closest-dates-in-sqlite-database-to-present-date) the question.

A quick snippet from the answer that could be relevant to you:

If you're use String as Data type in SQLite, you have to format System.currentTimeMillis() into Date format "yyyy/MM/dd". If you use other formats such as M/d/yyyy --> You will have date String comparing issues. See issue below for M/d/yyyy format:

```
"5/15/2015".compareTo("11/30/2015") ---> Return 4 > 0
--> means "5/15/2015" > "11/30/2015" --- Wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Date can be compared like this.. This may help you.

```
   select *  from MyTable 
   where mydate >= Datetime('2000-01-01 00:00:00') 
   and mydate <= Datetime('2050-01-01 23:00:59')
```